# Why can't VB.net find the class name using GetObject

Tags: vb.net, process, createobject

This is a follow-up to my previous [Question about GetObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004107/why-doesnt-code-work-in-vb-net-but-works-in-vba-getobject/21011980) This code:

```
Dim wb As Object ' Lotus123.Document
wb = GetObject("S:\Temp\T\0375D.WK3", "Lotus123.Workbook")
```

Works fine in VBA but fails in VB.net with the error: FileNotFoundException: "File name or class name not found during Automation operation."

I checked out the process with Process Monitor and found:
Both VBA and VB.net check these keys:

```
HKCR\Lotus123.Workbook\CLSID\(Default)
HKCR\CLSID\{29130007-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7}
HKCU\Software\Classes
```

Then VB.net simply stops

But VBA keeps on going with these keys

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\COM3\REGDBVersion
HKCR\CLSID\{29130007-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7}\InprocServer32    NAME NOT FOUND
HKCR\CLSID\{29130007-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7}\InprocServerX86   NAME NOT FOUND
HKCR\CLSID\{29130007-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7}\InprocServer32    NAME NOT FOUND
HKCR\CLSID\{29130007-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7}\InprocServerX86   NAME NOT FOUND
HKCR\CLSID\{29130007-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7}\LocalServer32 SUCCESS
HKCR\CLSID\{29130007-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7}\LocalServer32\(Default) SUCCESS
```

The last one gives the reward: Data: c:\lotus\123\123w.exe
And VBA goes on to open the 123w.exe program with the specified file.

So why can't VB.net find the class name? I don't understand why it simply quits looking.

Comment: VBA is usually 32-bit. What bitness is your VB.NET app?

Comment: @Heinzi my VB.net is is 32 bit also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a mismatch between the file name (gets spreadsheet document) and Lotus123.Workbook which returns the parent of the application object.

The code below works in XP 32 bit as well as in Win8 64 bit. I checked with process monitor what is happening under the hood. CreateObject checks for the CLSID in the registry using the given object. Then it looks up the necessary info using the CLSID.

```
Public Shared Function GetLotusWB(ByVal sFile As String) As Object

    'HKCU takes precedence if exists
    'HKCU\Software\Classes\Lotus123.Workbook\CLSID
    'HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{29130007-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7}

    'normally this is used because Lotus123 doesn't create HKCU entries
    'HKCR\Lotus123.Workbook\CLSID = {29130007-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7}
    'HKCR\CLSID\{29130007-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7}\InprocHandler32 = ole32.dll
    'HKCR\CLSID\{29130007-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7}\LocalServer32 = C:\Lotus\123\123w.exe

    'using object as that sometimes works better
    Dim LotusObj As Object = CreateObject("Lotus123.Workbook")

    'get application
    'need a reference to Lotus 123 else declare as Object
    Dim LotusApp As Lotus123.Application = LotusObj.Application
    'FAILS: LotusApp.Visible = True

    'open file; also works fine As Lotus123.Document
    Dim ldoc As Object = LotusApp.OpenDocument(sFile)

    'visible and activate (must declare as Object else gives exception)
    Dim appObject As Object = ldoc.Application 
    appObject.Visible = True
    ldoc.Activate()

    Return ldoc

End Function
```

In VB.net, this doesn't work `Dim wb As Object: wb = GetObject(sFile, "Lotus123.Workbook")` (worked in VBA)

In Win8 64bit this `wb = GetObject(sFile)` doesn't work; just hangs.

Comment: AFAIK GetObject/CreateObject is the only way to instantiate Lotus123 and manipulate it's objects.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason VB.net cannot find the class name "Lotus123.Workbook" so I tried getting the file without the class name and it works fine.

```
Dim wb As Object ' Lotus123.Document
wb = GetObject("S:\Temp\T\0375D.WK3")
```

Comment: But in Win8 64 bit this answer doesn't work. It just hangs; no exception, no nothing.

Answer (score -1):

you need to install office api or PIA (Primary Interop Assemblies) to get this working

you can find PIA for office 2010 here 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

find other versions by searching google

Comment: Maybe there's a misunderstanding: I don't want to use Excel or VBA (or its PIA). I was only using VBA to test the code that wasn't working in VB.net as expected. I want to start Lotus123 from VB.net. So I don't think Excel, VBA or the Office PIA is relevant at all.

Comment: when you call getobject with class name .net searches for interop lib for specified object (OLE registered object) so if you want to use lotus123 search for what api support lotus is providing it's nothing to do with .net or getobject

Comment: Well the documentation says to use GetObject. The CLSID points to the .exe instead of a PIA as it does with Excel. So Lotus doesn't seem to even have a PIA, yet once I have the Lotus123.Workbook it is not a problem to manipulate the objects it exposes.

Comment: What do you mean by "OLE registered object"? How can I tell if Lotus123 is OLE registered. I assume the answer is yes because I can add a COM reference to Lotus123 in my project.

Comment: In looking at the references in VB.net project, I discovered something else. A file (Interop.Lotus123.dll) was added to the \obj\Debug folder. Interesting...